# How to add &ZeroWidthSpace; in all letters of a text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cryptography

How do I add ​ in all letters of a text in react follows the example
`

```
    <h2>
      A&ZeroWidthSpace;L&ZeroWidthSpace;A&ZeroWidthSpace;N&ZeroWidthSpace;
    </h2>
```

This is my code

```
  const generateCryptography = async () => {
    var a = prompt
      .toLocaleUpperCase()
      .replace(/A/gi, "А")
      .replace(/P/gi, "Р")
      .replace(/C/gi, "С")
      .replace(/B/gi, "В")
      .replace(/T/gi, "Т")
      .replace(/S/gi, "Ѕ")
      .replace(/E/gi, "Е")
      .replace(/X/gi, "Х")
      .replace(/J/gi, "Ј")
      .replace(/H/gi, "Н")
      .replace(/O/gi, "О")
      .replace(/Y/gi, "Ү")
      .replace(/M/gi, "Μ")
      .replace(/N/gi, "Ν");
    setResult(a);
  };

  return (
    <div className="app-main">
      <>
        <h2>Criptografador de Texto</h2>

        <textarea
          className="app-input"
          placeholder="Cole o texto que deseja criptografar e clique no botão abaixo"
          onChange={(e) => setPrompt(e.target.value)}
          rows="10"
          cols="40"
        />
        <button onClick={generateCryptography}>Criptografar texto</button>
        <h1>{result}</h1>
      </>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried to solve this problem but I couldn't, I basically need the "​" always come after a letter after the user types in the input

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a string between all the characters in an input string, you can convert the string to an array and then join it with that filler.

```js
const string = "hey"
const filler = "&ZeroWidthSpace;"

function fillBetween(string, filler) {
  return [...string].join(filler)
}

console.log(fillBetween(string,filler))
```

Comment: the problem is that react in "App.jsx" it returns the &ZeroWidthSpace; as text by giving invisible space